# Live agent chat window customization

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-button, liveagent

I need to do some customization inside my live agent chat window and want to understand the possibilities

1. I have chatAlertMessage having dismisslabel = CLOSE when agent was not available for a particular time span but I want to redirect to any URL when the agent is not available. Is it possible??
2. How can I disable "AGENT IS TYPING" from the chat screen.
3. I want show an alert message in the screen when customer don't reply for 30 sec "Are you still there, Chat will be ended in 30 sec if you don't reply"